# Import of numpy fails with “initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception” on using the Python implementation of datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working with cpython-3.6 https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6

For datetime module, we have this code at the end which deletes all module level Python namespace declarations after importing the alternative (faster!) C implementation of datetime.

```
try:
    from _datetime import *
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    # Clean up unused names
    del (_DAYNAMES, _DAYS_BEFORE_MONTH, _DAYS_IN_MONTH, _DI100Y, _DI400Y,
         _DI4Y, _EPOCH, _MAXORDINAL, _MONTHNAMES, _build_struct_time,
         _check_date_fields, _check_int_field, _check_time_fields,
         _check_tzinfo_arg, _check_tzname, _check_utc_offset, _cmp, _cmperror,
         _date_class, _days_before_month, _days_before_year, _days_in_month,
         _format_time, _is_leap, _isoweek1monday, _math, _ord2ymd,
         _time, _time_class, _tzinfo_class, _wrap_strftime, _ymd2ord,
         _divide_and_round)
    # XXX Since import * above excludes names that start with _,
    # docstring does not get overwritten. In the future, it may be
    # appropriate to maintain a single module level docstring and
    # remove the following line.
    from _datetime import __doc__
```

I wanted to play around with the Python implementation of datetime so I commented out the code above. However as a result import of numpy (version 1.14) started failing with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<virtualenv dir>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "<virtualenv dir>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "<virtualenv dir>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "<virtualenv dir>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "<virtualenv dir>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception
```

I am working with an virtual env. I spawned my virtual env as:

```
virtualenv -p <path to cpython build> venv_python3
source <virtualenv dir>/bin/activate
<virtualenv dir>/bin/pip install numpy --no-cache-dir
```

FWIW, I found a workaround by moving the logic of importing C extension at the start of the module and commented out the lines to clean up unused names.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In 3.x, these "alternative implementations" are meant to be hidden "accelerators" that make no semantic changes—but many of them are left barely changed from 2.x when they were public alternative modules. Which means some of them do have differences, but they're usually considered bugs. If there's an actual difference, you should ideally search the [Python bug database](https://bugs.python.org/), and file and issue if you can't find it. If it's instead numpy making assumptions it shouldn't make, search for/file an issue at [numpy's github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues).

Comment: Meanwhile, for stuff like what you're doing, it's usually easier to fork and rename the stdlib module than to hack up what's there. It's pretty rare that any code in the rest of the stdlib or third-party code does an `isinstance` check or anything like that which would break it. But numpy is a special case for a lot of things, so it might…